# WP8 error media player can not start

Tags: c#, video, windows-phone-8

I'm  trying to play a small video file in my windows phone application. Is pretty basic

```
 void StartMediaPlayer()
    {
        MediaPlayerLauncher mediaPlayerLauncher = new MediaPlayerLauncher();

        mediaPlayerLauncher.Media = new Uri("/Assets/video/video1.wmv", UriKind.Relative);
        mediaPlayerLauncher.Location = MediaLocationType.Install;

        mediaPlayerLauncher.Controls = MediaPlaybackControls.All;
        mediaPlayerLauncher.Orientation = MediaPlayerOrientation.Landscape;

        mediaPlayerLauncher.Show();
    }
```

i call this void on image tap event, and this is what happend

[image]

the debugger show that the error is here: `mediaPlayerLauncher.Show();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if some has the same problem, just a heads up the files should be in main directory

```
mediaPlayerLauncher.Media = new Uri("video1.wmv", UriKind.Relative);
```

Answer (score 1):

That error will be thrown the application can't find your file `/Assets/video/video1.wmv` in the install directory on the phone. Make sure that your video is in your project, and is set to build type "Content". You could open the XAP file to double-check it's in the correct relative location too (it's just a ZIP file archive renamed).

Comment: this was the first thing i checked, i changed the location of the file and everything is still the same :( when i found out what the problem is i'm sure that it's gonna be something small and stupid